# ICANN Violation and Trademarks

Tags: domain-registration, top-level-domains

I'm trying to register a domain name with a .eg(i live in egypt) as the top-level domain. However, the local registrant told me to register a domain with the .eg extension i need to have a registered trademark. I dont think this makes much sense, is this a violation for any ICANN regulations, and if yes where i can find such documents?

Comment: What do you mean by "local registrant?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[All links to English versions.]

The requirements for registering an .eg domain name are [here](http://www.egregistry.eg/Roles&Policies.html).

Various TLDs have their own sets of requirements; there's no obvious violation of anything ICANN-related here. It looks like what you've been told *might* be half-true, depending upon exactly what name you're trying to register, and under what second-level domain, although I'm not so sure about use of the term "trademark" here. The .com.eg domain requires "commercial registry & taxation card" which I don't read as being the same thing.

Overall, the best thing for you to do would be to [ask them directly](http://www.egregistry.eg/Contact%20Us.htm) and get an official response. There's a [FAQ page](http://www.egregistry.eg/FAQ.html) that might cover your question, but I can't seem to get at the English version for it; if you can read it, give that a shot also.

Comment: well in the _Terms for second level domain_ registration, there are point 
 3 and 4 that are relevant:

3- The institution should have a trademark registered in Egypt regionally or internationally.
4- The institution should provide the trademark possession documents.,

but this is just plain restrictive, what do you think i can do about?

Comment: Whether the requirements are restrictive or not is interpretation; they manage the TLD, they set the rules. Either fulfill them, or pick another TLD. (I don't mean to be harsh, but that's just the actual answer to your question.) In the case of some other TLDs, I've seen registrars that do something like set up some kind of fake-but-official company for you, etc. but it's predictably *expensive* and I don't know of any for your case; I've never dealt with .eg or such services so can't really comment any further. I suppose you could look around for something similar.